# Confusion on Garbage Collection and Heap Dump data

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory, heap-dump

I tried triggering a couple of heap dumps in our application server at a particular time. Also on that time, I noted the garbage collection data.

I was trying to match the Tenured Data parameters with the value of the free & available heap from the heap dump and it doesn't match. Got me confused. Should they be equal or not?

Should Total consumed heap at a particular time be equal to Tenured Data (before) at the same time? if no is the answer, how can I match garbage collection data with heap dump data to make sure the data I am getting is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Collect Garbage collection data using -verbose:gc this consist the exact GC occupancy details similary collect Heapdump on user event. Load the Heapdump in 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/ to get the heap dump details and the verbose gc logs on 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/gcmv Match the details you will get the information you required.

Comment: I did view  gc and heap dump using their analyzers. My problem is the data from the two doesnt seem to match. Tenured Data (before) from gc data does not match consumed heap data from the heap dump at a particular instance

Comment: Do you have GC cycle information and the heap dump information? If you have please share it here. Myself Java Service Engineer i could help you in analysis.

Comment: Ok. Here is a snapshot of data recorded at 8am. Heap dump data at that time is consumed heap = 180MB. Garbage collection data: Used tenured (before) = 300MB & User tenured (after) = 120MB at 8am. Are they really not suppose to match?

Comment: Paste the complete GC cycle  taken at 8am

Comment: Which gc cycle parameter do you need ? since? af? completed? mark? sweep? compact? gc completed? overhead?

Comment: GC Cycle taken at 8am  consist start of the GC cycle till it get completed.

Comment: Where in the garbage collection analyzer can i see that?

Comment: is there a way where i can chat with you about this? so we would flood the thread with comments